# String to Date with leading X character

Tags: r, string, date, format, character

I'm trying to convert the `Date` column to date format but I keep getting an error. I think the problem might be that the date is a character and has an X before the year:

```
HMC.Close        Date
1     39.71 X2007.01.03
2     40.04 X2007.01.04
3     38.67 X2007.01.05
4     38.89 X2007.01.08
5     38.91 X2007.01.09
6     37.94 X2007.01.10
```

This is the code I've been running:

```r
stock_honda <- expand.grid("HMC" = HMC$HMC.Close) %>%
  "Date" = as.Date(row.names(as.data.frame(HMC))) %>% 
  subset(Date >"2021-02-28" & Date < "2022-03-11")
```

> Error in charToDate(x) :
> character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: you may be able to go upstream in your data processing pipeline and prevent those "X" characters from getting introduced into the rownames in the first place ... ?

Comment: Hi Ben, that would be great since I have many data frames like this. How could I prevent them?

Comment: We would need to know more about your workflow. At a guess, these are caused by reading in a data frames with *column names* representing dates (e.g. 2007.01.03). If you use `read.*` functions from base R (e.g. `read.table()`), then specifying `check.names = FALSE` will turn off X-protection.  If you use `read_*` functions from the `readr` package (e.g. `readr::read_table`), then this protection is turned off by default.

Comment: I used the `quantmode` package and downloaded the data frames directly from it. Could I add `check.names = FALSE` even when I don't use a `read.*`function ?

Comment: This is the code I used:                                              
`install.packages("quantmod")
library(quantmod)

 getSymbols(c("FCAU.VI", "TYO", "VWAGY", "HMC"), na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: you must have done something after that, because it doesn't (apparently) return a data frame; when I run this package I end up with 4 objects in my global environment (with the names of the downloaded symbols), each is an `xts` object with dates as row indices and several columns.  How did you convert these objects to a data frame with an `HMC.Close` and a `Date` column?

Comment: After I ran this code (which already has the corrections you gave me): `stock_honda <- expand.grid("HMC" = HMC$HMC.Close) %>%
  mutate(Date = row.names(as.data.frame(HMC))) %>%
  mutate(across(Date, ~ . %>% str_remove("^X") %>% ymd())) %>% 
  subset(Date >"2021-02-28" & Date < "2022-03-11")`

Comment: But without the code: `mutate(across(Date, ~ . %>% str_remove("^X") %>% ymd()))`, the Date column was a string type and han an "X".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pipeline that avoids prepending "X" to the dates in the first place:

```r
library(quantmod)
getSymbols(c("FCAU.VI", "TYO", "VWAGY", "HMC"), na.rm = TRUE)

library(tidyverse)
stock_honda <- (HMC
  %>% as.data.frame()
  %>% rownames_to_column("Date")
  %>% select(Date, HMC.Close)
  %>% mutate(across(Date, lubridate::ymd))
  %>% filter(between(Date, as.Date("2021-02-28"), as.Date("2022-03-11")))
)
```

It would be nice if there were a version of `between` that avoided the need to explicitly convert to dates. (`filter("2021-02-28" < Date, Date < "2022-03-11")` would also work for the last step.)

Comment: I'll for sure use this pipeline instead, it's much more readable. Thank you Ben!

Comment: if one of the answers solved your problem, you're encouraged to click on the check-mark to accept it (which one is up to you)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `gsub` to first remove the "X" that is causing a problem and then use `ymd` from `lubridate` package to convert the strings into Dates. Additionally, you can make that conversion using `mutate(across(...))` from the `dplyr` package to do everything in a tidyverse-way.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df |>
  # Mutate Date to remove X and convert it to Date
  mutate(across(Date, function(x){
    ymd(gsub("X","", x))
  }))

#  HMC.Close       Date
#1     39.71 2007-01-03
#2     40.04 2007-01-04
#3     38.67 2007-01-05
#4     38.89 2007-01-08
#5     38.91 2007-01-09
#6     37.94 2007-01-10
```

Comment: or to be more tidyverse-ish, use `mutate(across(Date, ~ . %>% str_remove("^X") %>% ymd()))`

Comment: Thank you @JonathanV.Solórzano and Ben Bolker! Both codes worked perfectly!